# Cannot set tabPage image to a tabControl C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a `ImageList`, with one item, in the `TabControl`:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ImageList tabControlMain_ilMain;
this.TabControlMain.ImageList = this.tabControlMain_ilMain;

this.tabControlMain_ilMain.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("tabControlMain_ilMain.ImageStream")));
this.tabControlMain_ilMain.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
this.tabControlMain_ilMain.Images.SetKeyName(0, "");
```

and I am setting this image to a specific `TabPage`:

```
this.tabControlMain_tp17.ImageIndex = 0;
```

and I can see in the designer the image attached to the `TabPage`, but when I am running the application, I cannot see the image, it is just an empty space near the `TabPage` name.

Does anyone know what could be the problem ?

Thank you!

P.S. What I have seen is that, if I am not selecting the `ImageIndex`, the `TabPage` header is getting less length, so I guess the image is taking the space, but cannot see it at runtime.

Comment: did you create an instance of `tabControlMain_ilMain` like so `this.tabControlMain_ilMain = new System.Windows.Forms.ImageList(this.components);`

Comment: yes, I have created, in the `InitializeComponent().`

Comment: Mind adding your complete code of the Designer.cs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did nothing different than you i think. But mine is working.
Maybe remove and readd the controls.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
  this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
  System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
  this.TabControlMain = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
  this.tabControlMain_tp17 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
  this.tabControlMain_ilMain = new System.Windows.Forms.ImageList(this.components);
  this.TabControlMain.SuspendLayout();
  this.SuspendLayout();
  // 
  // TabControlMain
  // 
  this.TabControlMain.Controls.Add(this.tabControlMain_tp17);
  this.TabControlMain.ImageList = this.tabControlMain_ilMain;
  this.TabControlMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(44, 42);
  this.TabControlMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 191);
  // 
  // tabControlMain_tp17
  // 
  this.tabControlMain_tp17.ImageIndex = 0;
  this.tabControlMain_tp17.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 23);
  this.tabControlMain_tp17.Text = "tabControlMain_tp17";
  // 
  // tabControlMain_ilMain
  // 
  this.tabControlMain_ilMain.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("tabControlMain_ilMain.ImageStream")));
  this.tabControlMain_ilMain.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
  this.tabControlMain_ilMain.Images.SetKeyName(0, "");
  // 
  // Form1
  // 
  this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
  this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
  this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
  this.Controls.Add(this.TabControlMain);
  this.TabControlMain.ResumeLayout(false);
  this.ResumeLayout(false);

}

private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl TabControlMain;
private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabControlMain_tp17;
private System.Windows.Forms.ImageList tabControlMain_ilMain;
```